# Equidistribution summing over the euclidean ball

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, equidistribution

Given a vector $v\in \mathbb{Z}^d\setminus\{0\}$, an irrational number $\eta$ and some $M>0$ is it true that$$\Big(\frac{\sqrt{d}}{M}\Big)^{d}\sum_{w\in \mathbb{Z}^d\cap B(0, M)}\exp(2\pi i \eta \cdot \langle v, w \rangle)\to 0,$$ when $M\to \infty$, where $B(0,M)$ is the euclidean ball of radius $M$ and center $0$? Is there some general equidistibution theorem I can use to prove it?

Comment: How do you define the exponential of a vector and what does it mean then to tend to $0$? It does look like something related to Weyl's criterion for equidistribution in the multivariate case for points on the sphere but does not make much sense as it is phrased.

Comment: It think it's not the exponential of a vector because we are taking the inner product with $v$ so this expression gives a complex number.

Comment: But there is no other vector

Comment: In multidimensional Weyls Criterion/ Fourier you have an inner product and it does give a number in the end but here I fail to see it

Comment: there is a fixed vector $v$ and we are summing over vectors $w\in \mathbb{Z}^d\cap B(0,M)$ and taking for each one of those the inner product with $v$.

Comment: Ah true, I dismissed the obvious inner product notation as a vector due to that dot. Sometimes people use this $\langle\rangle$ to signify a vector

Comment: Would really help if you pointed out how you came across this problem. It seems realy interesting and looks like a multidimensional generalization of Weyl's Theorem but inside a sphere. This is in that sense a proof of the equidistribution of $\eta{}w$ in the unit ball. Perhaps proving equidistribution in the unit square would be easier and then automatically imply equidistribution in the unit ball.